# Creating asp buttons with different text depending on value of a field in repeater

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, button, dynamic, repeater

For my .NET project I have to output data from an access file to a repeater and generate buttons next to each item in order for customers to rent the items displayed. I've been trying to find a way to generate buttons with different text depending on the value of a field in the repeater. More specifically, I'd like the button to say "rent for £3.50" if price_band is A and "rent for £2.50" if price_band is B. Up to now I've tried several approaches to no avail. Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <div class="list-group-item active"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><img src="<%# Eval("image")%>" /></p> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><%# Eval("title")%></h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><strong>Director: </strong><%# Eval("director")%></p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><strong>Cast: </strong><%# Eval("cast")%></p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><strong>Genre: </strong><%# Eval("genre")%></p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><strong>Year Released: </strong><%# Eval("year_released")%></p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><strong>Rating: </strong><%# Eval("rating")%></p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><strong>IMDB Score: </strong><%# Eval("imdb_rating")%></p>
        <p class="list-group-item-text"><strong>Price Band: </strong><%# Eval("price_band")%></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-1">
        <% if (Session["customer"] != null) { %>
          <%if("price_band" == "A"){%>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRent" runat="server" Text="Rent for £3.50"/> 
          <% } %>
          <%else if("price_band" == "B"){%>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRent1" runat="server" Text="Rent for £2.50"/> 
          <% } %>                                                                                   
        <% }
        else { %>
          <asp:Button ID="btnLoginWarning" runat="server" Text="Must be logged in to rent"/>
        <%} %>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: What happens when you try to run this? Also, you have an if and an else if, but no else. Also, "price_band" will never == "A and price_band will never == "B" "price_band" == "price_band"

Comment: If I am not logged in, multiple instances of "btnLoginWarning" are generated, which is correct. If I am logged in however, nothing is generated, which is wrong. Could you explain more about price_band=price_band? If this is the case how could I evaluate it correctly? Thanks

Comment: Because you have "price_band" in quotes, it is just a string. If it is a variable, you need to remove the quotes. If it is a session variable you need Session["price_band"]

Comment: price_band is a field in the access data file from which I am retrieving my data. It gets evaluated and outputed in the repeater via: <p class="list-group-item-text"><strong>Price Band: </strong><%# Eval("price_band")%></p>

Comment: So in the if statement, you should use Eval("price_band") and not just "price_band"

Comment: Doing this gives me the error "Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control." and I haven't found anything useful to solve this error